# Django: Sumar dos campos DurationField

Tags: python, django, sql

estoy creando un proyecto en Django, mi modelo tiene dos campos donde sumo las horas de duración de una actividad realizada, en mi vista realizo un consulta donde sumo el total de horas de actividades por alumno pero quiero sumar duracion_dft con duracion_dfp, ¿cómo puedo hacer eso?

**Modelo**

```
class Actividad(models.Model):
    duracion_dft = models.DurationField('Duración horas teóricas HH:MM:SS', default=datetime.timedelta(minutes=0))
    duracion_dfp = models.DurationField('Duración horas prácticas HH:MM:SS', default=datetime.timedelta(minutes=0))
```

**Vista**

```
def curso(request, id=id):
    consulta = Estudiante.objects.filter(idCurso=id).annotate(teorica=Sum('actividad__duracion_dft'), presencial=Sum('actividad__duracion_dfp'), total=Sum(F('actividad__duracion_dft')+F('actividad__duracion_dfp')))
```

**Resultado**

- teorica = 0:00:00
- presencial = 2:50:00
- total = 0:00:00.000002

Comment: Cual es el problema?

Comment: @Onilol al sumar las horas teóricas y presenciales deberían dar 2:50:00 (2hr 50 min 00 seg) pero el resultado es 0:00:00.000002 ¿Cómo puedo sumar esos campos y que el resultado sigan con el formato de horas?